# Files show up in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio with a shortcut icon. What does that mean?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I've downloaded FParsec's library source code, and all the files appear with the shortcut symbol. What does it mean?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the item was added to that project, it was added as a link `Project -> Add Existing Item -> Add as Link`

The file is most likely hosted in another location in the directory structure, and can also be referenced normally by another project.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92.aspx):

> Adding an Existing Item as a Link
>
> You can also add an item as a link rather than directly adding the
>   file to your project. Linked project items in Solution Explorer can be
>   identified by the link indicator in its icon (a small arrow in the
>   lower left corner).
>
> By linking to a file, you can capture ongoing changes to a source file
>   without having to manually update a copy whenever changes are made.
>   However, if the underlying file is deleted, the link will be broken.
>   If you move your project, the link will be broken, because the link is
>   relative.