# Solution Explorer cannot find "rename" option when right click. There are unusual blue icon on each item. What does the blue icon means?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, csproj, solution-explorer

I managed to move the .csproj (C# projects) to the outside to the other folder. Then, manually edit the path of its (.csproj) components(such as *.cs, the form, settings, etc.). Yes.. It successfully build! But... I can't rename the component. When I right click on the item, I can't find the "rename" option on the popup showed. I also couldn't type  to change the file name in the property pages (it disabled). Here the picture:

[Click here to show the picture I mean...](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AkDuqcVt4VdWRMhQjvbWM0aupX1cv_En/view?usp=sharing)

Note: In the picture, there were small blue icon (like arrow). I think it is the sign of the problem. But i can't find any reference refer to it.

Questions:

(1) How can I fix it, so it can be renamed?

(2) What the small blue icon means? Can you show any reference?

Comment: Looks like those files are *linked items*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Files show up in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio with a shortcut icon. What does that mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141310/files-show-up-in-solution-explorer-in-visual-studio-with-a-shortcut-icon-what-d)

Answer (score 0):

I run across a similar problem with Solution Explorer of VS2022. No rename option, but if you right click on a file and choose "Open Containing Folder", and then rename file, then once back into the Solution Explorer you see the item renamed as well

Comment: Rename and Remove right-click menus were missing for me while I was debugging. I stopped debugging and the options reappeared.

Comment: exiting debug mode also brought back the rename functionality! thanks @foes for your tip!